# Python string identity: `is` and `in` statements

Tags: python, string

I had some problems getting this to work:

```
# Shortened for brevity
def _coerce_truth(word):
    TRUE_VALUES = ('true','1','yes')
    FALSE_VALUES = ('false','0','no')

    _word = word.lower().strip()
    print "t" in _word
    if _word in TRUE_VALUES:
        return True
    elif _word in FALSE_VALUES:
        return False
```

I discovered:

```
In [20]: "foo" is "Foo".lower()
Out[20]: False

In [21]: "foo" is "foo".lower()
Out[21]: False

In [22]: "foo" is "foo"
Out[22]: True

In [23]: "foo" is "foo".lower()
Out[23]: False
```

Why is this? I understand that identity is different then equality, but when is identity formed? Statement 22 should be `False` unless, due to the static nature of strings, id == eq. In this case I'm confused by statement 23.

Please explain and thanks in advance.

Comment: More to this: `'foo' is 'foo'[:]` is still true

Comment: This is about optimisation - as strings are immutable Python will automatically share instances of strings in your source code - they will be the same object. There is no guarantee of this, however. It should definitely not be relied upon.

Comment: Can you clarify how `is` and `in` are behaving relative to each other, and what you expected?

Comment: It's very rare that you want to use `is` in Python. Use `==` instead.

Answer (score 7):

Q. "When is identity formed?"

A. When the object is created.

What you're seeing is actually an implementation detail of Cpython -- It caches small strings and reuses them for efficiency.  Other cases that are interesting are:

```
"foo" is "foo".strip()  # True
"foo" is "foo"[:]       # True
```

Ultimately, what we see is that the string literal `"foo"` has been cached.  Every time you type `"foo"`, you're referencing the same object in memory.  However, some string methods will choose to always create new objects (like `.lower()`) and some will smartly re-use the input string if the method made no changes (like `.strip()`).

---

One benefit of this is that string equality can be implemented by a pointer compare (blazingly fast) followed by a character-by-character comparison if the pointer comparison is false.  If the pointer comparison is True, then the character-by-character comparison can be avoided.

Comment: I’m seeing `'foo' is 'foo'.lower()` is `True` in Python 3.

Comment: Probably because `lower` is implemented as an in-place list operation in Python3. It's not in Python2.

Comment: @JoshLee -- Well, it looks like implementation details hold true to their name then :).  The take-away is that if it's implementation dependent, then you shouldn't rely on that behavior since it's likely to be different for you compared to me.

Answer (score 3):

As for relation between `is` and `in`:

The `__contains__` method (which stands behind `in` operator) for `tuple` and `list` while looking for a match, first checks the identity and if that fails checks for equality. This gives you sane results even with objects that don't compare equal to themselves:

```
>>> x = float("NaN")
>>> t = (1, 2, x)
>>> x in (t)
True
>>> any(x == e for e in t) # this might be suprising
False
```

Comment: The properties of `nan` not being equal to itself is irrelevant to the question. `float('nan')==float('nan')` is always False

Comment: @Pyson: NaN is only an example why ``in`` needs to check for identity instead of just checking for equality.

Comment: Most specifically, it *first* checks for identity, *then* equality if identity turns out `False`.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a bunch of ways of creating objects that have the string value of 'foo':

```
def f(s): return s.lower()

li=['foo',                     # 0
    'foo'.lower(),             # 1
    'foo'.strip(),             # 2
    'foo',                     # 3
    'f'+'o'*2,                 # 4
    '{}'.format('foo'),        # 5
    'f'+'o'+'o',               # 6
    intern('foo'.lower()),     # 7
    'foo'.upper().lower(),     # 8
    f('foo'),                  # 9
    'FOO'.lower(),             # 10
    'foo',                     # 11
    format('foo'),             # 12
    '%s'%'foo',                # 13
    '%s%s'%('fo','o'),         # 14
    'f'   'oo'                 # 15
]
```

`is` will only resolve to `True` if the objects have the same [id](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#id). You can test this and see which string objects have been [interned](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning) into the same immutable string at runtime:

```
def cat(l):
    d={}
    for i,e in enumerate(l):
        k=id(e)
        d.setdefault(k,[]).append(i)

    return '\n'.join(str((k,d[k])) for k in sorted(d))
```

Prints:

```
(4299781024, [0, 2, 3, 6, 7, 11, 12, 13, 15])
(4299781184, [5])
(4299781784, [1])
(4299781864, [4])
(4299781904, [9])
(4299782944, [8])
(4299783064, [10])
(4299783144, [14])
```

You can see that most resolve (or are interned) to the same string object, but some do not. Which is implementation dependent.

You can make them be all the same string object by using the function [intern](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#intern):

```
print cat([intern(s) for s in li])
```

Prints:

```
(4299781024, [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15])
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this helps.  If you change it to `'foo'.strip()`, you get pretty much the same `dis` output, but different results.  Is your point the `LOAD_CONST` part?